# @material-ui/styles ( 4.0.0-beta.1 ) issue with 'withStyle' mechanism

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

Im a currently implementing a menu in ReactJs using Material-Ui.
I am customizing the  so has to change paddings in css using the 'CSS in JS' approach.
However , styles are not always applied. Looking at the generated  tags , its seems my style gets overriden by the MuiBaseButton which css rule takes precedence over mine ( which i guess should not happen since the JSS plugin should render my  last so it should be more specific. Had a look a the page and actually its as if material-ui rendered the MuiBaseButton multiple times ( before and after my own React component's style with the 'withStyle' method so that it never gets a chance to have the 'navItemStyles'

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import * as React from 'react';
import classNames from 'classnames';

import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import Tooltip from '@material-ui/core/Tooltip';
import withStyles from '@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles';
import { Theme, WithStyles } from '@material-ui/core';
import { UxUseCase } from '../../UxTypes';

[...]

export const navItemStyles = (theme: Theme) => ({
[...]
    bananaman: {
        border: '3px solid yellow'
    },
});

[...]
class UxSidebarNavItem extends React.Component<UxSidebarNavItemProperties & WithStyles<any>> {
[...]
public render(): React.ReactNode {
[...]
        const listClass = classNames(classes.bananaman);

       return (
            <Tooltip title={item.label}>
                <ListItem
                    ContainerComponent="a"
                    button
                    key={item.id}
                    className={listClass}
                    href={item.useCase ? item.useCase.bookmark : ''}
                    onClick={this.handleOnClick}
                >
                    HAHA
                    <span className={itemClass}>{item.label}</span>
                </ListItem>
            </Tooltip>
        );
[...]
export default withStyles(navItemStyles)(UxSidebarNavItem);
```

Here , i am expected the      border: '3px solid yellow' to be set , but the default style from MuiBaseButton is set instead.

Comment: mmm I am not an expert but, why do you use `'classNames(classes.bananaman)' `?  I have used this in the past succesfully only with lets say `<Button className='classes.bananaman' />`

Comment: I would also like to know why you add `<UxSidebarNavItemProperties & WithStyles<any>>` when extending react comp, is that new?

Comment: Please create a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) that reproduces your issue. I did not see any issue when trying your styling here: https://codesandbox.io/s/jv7nm4k3y9